# Creating a system-wide Panning effect on android

Tags: android, audio, soundpool, audiosession

I would like to build an app that continuously pans the android audio (system-wide) from side to side.
I haven't found any way to do this. I found one app that can change the audio balance for all apps but I don't know how it does that and couldn't reach the author. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jazibkhan.equalizer&hl=en_US&pli=1

Anyone have an idea?

I have considered using Virtualizer from the android audio apk but it cant receive specific spatial data.
I have considered using google resonance audio but I don't think it can be applied system wide.

Comment: I believe modifying the entire system-wide audio, should require changes in the Android OS itself?